# google maps multiple markers in php not working

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

to put map in my site i follow one example and it will display static markers like.

```
var locations = [
['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];
```

i want it dynamic from mysql table. it has lat and lng. i tried this but not working

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $db_name = "aarya";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";

    $con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password) or die("connection error");

    mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("could't connect to database");

    $query="SELECT * FROM detail";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
var locations = [
  ['<?php echo $row['name'];?>','<?php echo $row['lat'];?>','<?php echo $row['lng'];?>'],
<?php
}
?>
];
```

i think problem in locations array and i am new in google maps please help me.

Comment: Have you looked into using php's json_encode function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a rough example of doing this:

Your `locations` array:

```
<?php
$locations[0] = array("lat"=>"-33.890542", "long"=>"151.274856", "info" => "Bondi Beach");
$locations[1] = array("lat"=>"-33.923036", "long"=>"151.259052", "info" => "Coogee Beach");
$locations[2] = array("lat"=>"-34.028249", "long"=>"151.157507", "info" => "Cronulla Beach");
$locations[3] = array("lat"=>"-33.80010128657071", "long"=>"151.28747820854187", "info" => "Manly Beach");
$locations[4] = array("lat"=>"-33.950198", "long"=>"151.259302", "info" => "Maroubra Beach");
?>
```

Or you could query the database like:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM detail";
$result=mysql_query($query);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $locations[] = array("lat"=>$row['lat'], "long"=>$row['lng'], "info" => $row['name']);
}
?>
```

You can modify the above array with the values from your database.
The map:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            body { font: normal 10pt Helvetica, Arial; }
            #map { width: 350px; height: 300px; border: 0px; padding: 0px; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
        new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
        var center = null;
        var map = null;
        var currentPopup;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        function addMarker(lat, lng, info)
        {
            var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            bounds.extend(pt);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: pt,
                icon: icon,
                map: map
            });
            var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
            {
                content: info,
                maxWidth: 300
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function()
            {
                if (currentPopup != null)
                {
                    currentPopup.close();
                    currentPopup = null;
                }
                popup.open(map, marker);
                currentPopup = popup;
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function()
            {
                map.panTo(center);
                currentPopup = null;
            });
        }

        function initMap()
        {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            zoom: 0,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions:
            {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
            },
            navigationControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions:
            {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            }
            });
            <?php foreach($locations AS $loc) { //you could replace this with your while loop query ?>
                addMarker(<?php echo $loc["lat"]; ?>, <?php echo $loc["long"]; ?>, '<?php echo $loc["info"]; ?>');
            <?php } ?>
            center = bounds.getCenter();
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initMap()" style="margin:0px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
    <div id="map"></div>
</html>
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: my database is changing every time so i want it dynamic.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya Just query your database and keep `$locations` in the loop, assigning values of keys `lat`, `long` & `info`

Comment: i query my database but i don't know how to assign it.if u give me example.it will be nice one.

Comment: it is displaying blank page.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya check the browser's console, also check what you get when you do a `print_r($locations);`

Comment: print_r($locations); only displaying one array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89058/discussion-between-criesto-and-divyesh-jesadiya).

Comment: here,only markers are added,how can i add markers with name?

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya if you click on any of the marker you'll see the info associated with that marker.

Comment: it is possible if i want to display name without click and onclick i want to give link?

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya Yes, you'll have to change the `click listener` in the js code.

Answer (score 0):

You are initialising var locations everytime your while loop is running . In that aspect you will have the value of only the last iteration.Please initialise locations outside and push the values inside the javascript array.Also you should consider json_encode way .It is much cleaner.

Comment: i don't know json_encode way.from where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

if you new at google maps you can use gmaps.js it allows you to use the potential of Google Maps in a simple way.

https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

and its marker example:
https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/markers.html

I think you need to use objects:

```
var locations = {
    {
        title: '<?= $row['name'] ?>',
        lat: '<?= $row['lat'] ?>',
        lng: '<?= $row['lng'] ?>'
    }
}
```

And you can use json_encode instead

Answer (score 0):

In your code you already have following locations available globally:

```
var locations = [
['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856],
['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052],
['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507],
['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302]
];
```

Now add the following `HTML` and `Javascript` in your file and refresh the page. This will show you the Google map.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div>;
```

**Javascript**

```
function loadMap()
{
  var map;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  };
  // Display a map on the page
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  for( i = 0; i < locations.length; i++ ) {
    var loc = locations[i];
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1], loc[2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: loc[0]
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMap);
```

Comment: that is example that i follow.my code is second one.

Comment: Did it help you? Please care to share your final outcome as that might help others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically use your database please check this example.

Create the file map3.php. File same as here

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db('yourdatabase');

function parseToXML($htmlStr)
{
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','<',$htmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','>',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','"',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",''',$xmlStr);
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&',$xmlStr);
return $xmlStr;
}

$query = mysql_query("select * from yourtable");



//header("Content-type: text/html");

/* Get lat and Lan using table query */
$i=0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){


$reposnse['markers'][$i]['lat']= $row['lat'];
$reposnse['markers'][$i]['lag']= $row['lag'];


$i++;
}

echo json_encode($reposnse);
?>

After create map2.php same as here

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="application/javascript">





     $(document).ready(function(e) {



$.ajax({
url:"map3.php",
dataType: 'json',
success: function(result){
var html = '<markers>';


for (var prop in result['markers']) {

var value = result['markers'][prop];
//alert(value.lat);
html += '<marker ';
html += 'lat="';
html += value.lat+'"';
html += 'lng="';
html += value.lag+'"';
html += '/>';
}
html += '</markers>';
$('#test').html(html);

function initialize() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 6,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(15.317277,75.71389),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker;

        var location = {};


var markers = document.getElementsByTagName("marker");


        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

//alert(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
            location = {
                name : 'test'+i,
                address : 'baglore',
                city : 'bangalore',
                state : 'Karnataka',
                zip : '560017',
                pointlat : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                pointlng : parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))  
            };

            console.log(location);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(location.pointlat, location.pointlng),
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker,location) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(location.name);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                };
            })(marker, location));
        }
  }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

},
});

    });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test">
    </div>

    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please check the link below [Adding multiple markers to google maps using javascript and php](http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2016/06/adding-multiple-markers-to-google-maps-javascript-and-php.html)